# Implementing a Quest System in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good day all.

I'm working on a story-driven game in Unity3D and I want to have quests the player must complete to progress through the story.

What would be the best and most efficient way to implement a quest system?

**Currently I have the following data structure in mind:**

- Quest (Class)

  - Quest name
  - Quest description
  - Quest Reward
  - Quest Location
  - Is it a side quest?
  - What's the name of the main quest?
  - Is it necessary to continue main quest?
- QuestManager (Class)

  - List of all quests
  - What quest is the play currently pursuing?
  - List of objectives and side quests of the current quest
  - What objective is the play suppose to complete in the current quest?
  - Checks whether the player has completed a quest/objective/side quest    and handles events accordingly

The data structure looks pretty reasonable but I don't know how to implement in such a generic way that I can easily and quickly create quests in my game. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see what the issue is. What you listed is very generic and reasonable. What is confusing about implementing it? For each bullet point either use a built-in type or write your own class

Comment: @GordonAllocman The confusion starts after you've made each of the individual parts of the quest system and have to connect them all to create the ultimate functionality of it. It would be less confusing if someone took those bullet points and showed me an example of how they would be connected together to achieve that functionality

Comment: I would imagine the player has a QuestManager instance, and you already said QuestManager has a list of all quests so that's how it all pieces together. This is just one possible way to do it, you may realize you need to change it as you go but thats definitely a reasonable start. I would suggest you attempt to create the classes yourself and if you run into confusion then post the code you tried and where you got stuck

Comment: Have your QuestManager as a singleton instance. And then simply build all your quest objects from there and allow the QuestManger to do its job of managing them, marking them complete, etc, based on the quest's criteria.

Comment: @GordonAllocman I'll start with the coding of it and see how far I get alone, will update post if I encounter problems on the way. Thanks

Comment: @ManoDestra will keep in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The general idea you have seems fine. I would modify things a bit. I would probably make the Quest reward also a class. That way it's easier to customize the rewards.. I would also make "What's the name of the main quest?" an method which grabs a Quest object(if it exists). This way you can easily just reference the parent quest from within the sub-quest.

I am assuming your using a database to store all this information? If not I'd suggest using sqlite.

This way, all that's required to add more quests, etc. is to send an updated database file out to your users. It's pretty easy/fast to just add data to a db also. No hard coding quests etc.

So you create these Quest classes as Models, fill out the data, and then convert that object into JSON. It can then be stored in the database. Once it's pulled out you can convert the Json back into a Quest Object.

Use [Newton-soft Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to do this, along with [Sqlite](http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/)

Or you can also do it this way: [Walkthrough: Simple Object Model and Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386940%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not using a database and I couldn't use it for quests in the context of my game since all the quest locations are unique. I'll keep whatever everyone has said in mind and start writing the quest system. Will post updates

Comment: @Tayab Just because the locations are unique doesn't mean you can't use a database... Quite the opposite.